# Scroll area incorrect when editing UITextField on UITableViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` of grouped style, on iPhone.  I'm on iOS 7.0.6 now.  On some of my cells are `UITextField`'s.  When editing a text field, the scroll area is adjusted automatically; I have not added code to do this.  The only scrolling related thing I have is:

```
[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:nameIndexPath
                      atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
                              animated:YES];
```

But I only call this in `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` so it's not even called when I tap a text field.

My issue is that, with the keyboard visible, I can scroll up the table contents too far.  It seems to be precisely a tab bar height too far; my app is tab bar based.  On the image below you can see that the scroll bar stops one tab bar height above the keyboard.  (Unimportant note: The text field is scrolled all the way up, so you can't see it.)

Looks like yet another iOS 7 bug.  Any ideas how I can work around this, because it looks rather sloppy.

[image]

Note: I've seen similar inset issues with iOS in other situations.  I guess will be fixed soon (at least I hope so; because these a very iOS simple bugs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that both `contentInset` and `scrollIndicatorInsets` are incorrect: `(64, 0, **265**, 0)`.  The bottom inset value is 55 point (i.e., tab bar height) off.

The correct bottom inset must of course be just the keyboard height `216`.

To work around it until Apple get their act together:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField*)textField
{
    dispatch_time_t when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.6 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(when, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {
        // Must be delayed until after iOS has adjusted the insets,
        // which turns out to be 'way before' the keyboard animation has finished.
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 216, 0)];
        [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 216, 0)];
    });

    return YES;
}
```

and:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    // iOS seems to set the insets differential: So we must set them back
    // to the incorrect values for iOS to subtract the bottom inset back
    // to 55 again.
    // No delay needed here of course because we must do this before the
    // keyboard animation starts.
    [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 265, 0)];
    [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 265, 0)];

    return YES;
}
```

EDIT: To make sure this workaround is Apple fix resistant, let's do:

```
dispatch_time_t when = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.6 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(when, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
{
    if (self.tableView.contentInset.bottom == 265)
    {
        [self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 216, 0)];
        [self.tableView setScrollIndicatorInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(64, 0, 216, 0)];
    }
});
```